# What are the possible domains to use with a Microsoft account

Tags: outlook.com, microsoft-account

I recently created a new Microsoft account with `@outlook.com`. This and `@hotmail.com` were the only options available.

Now today on a different computer, `@outlook.de` also showed up.

Is there a way to see all available domains? I’m particularly interested in `@outlook.ch`.